# Ubuntu 20.04 occasionally disables key repetition

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-20.04

I don't know how or why, sometimes, suddenly, for no apparent reason, key repetition is disabled.
If I run this command:

```
 xset r on
```

or if I wait half an hour, the key repetition starts working again but after a few days the problem suddenly returns.
I think it's because xorg or another system program suddenly crashes, but that's just a guess.

I have no idea of the cause of the problem, so I ask whoever has the same problem, if they have been able to diagnose it.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit freshly installed.

There is a similar problem in Ubuntu 8.04 LTS, if it matches my problem, it would mean the bug hasn't been fixed for 12 years!:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/272293?comments=all

Answer (score 1):

Reset keyboard settings to default

First do a dump of any keyboard settings that differ from default

```bash
dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/

# => [org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/keyboard]
# => delay=uint32 188
# => numlock-state=true
# => repeat=true
# => repeat-interval=uint32 0
```

Then reset them back to defaults

```bash
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/
```

Danger proceed with care (you probably don't need to do anything beyond here)

Dump all changes

```bash
dconf dump /
```

Reset all settings back to default

```bash
dconf reset -f /
```